# Displaying Extension Library Dialog box when page loads?

Tags: xpages

Is there any way to display an extension pages dialog  box when my page loads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `<xp:scriptBlock />` with the following client-side code as its `value`:

`XSP.addOnLoad(function(){XSP.openDialog("#{id:dlgMessage}");});`

...just be sure to place the component outside any refresh targets, or it will launch the dialog again after every partial refresh event with a target that includes it.

Comment: I gave this a try.  See above since you really can't format comments very well on this form.

Comment: Glad to hear :) P.S. to format text in a comment as `code`, surround it in reverse apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a dojo.addOnLoad() (in a xp:scriptblock) that displays the dialog using CSJS: XSP.openDialog()

Comment: LOL... GET OUT OF MY MIND! :)

Comment: HA HA. Yes, what Tim said with more details :-)

Answer (score 0):

Bruce,

You could use jQuery to 'push' the button on page load.

Try putting this clientside js code in your onClientLoad event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.btn').trigger('click');
});
```

You will have to load jQuery to use this if you don't already have it loaded.  You might also be able to do the same thing with dojo.

EDIT:  You might have to modify the selector (the tag and class in the parens line 2) above if not using bootstrap.  I would give it a unique class so as not to 'push' any other buttons at the same time.