# Calling "param.get" Client side?

Tags: xpages

Thanks to the great help on this forum, I was able to get this working:

[Displaying Extension Library Dialog box when page loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101662/displaying-extension-library-dialog-box-when-page-loads)

Now what I need to do is not display the dialog box if a parameter is not in the URL. I can do this server side with param.get.     How can I get the parameter client side?   or is there some work araound?

Answer (score 2):

`<xp:scriptBlock rendered="#{not(empty(param.showDialog))}">...`

...or, if you want to check for a specific value:

`<xp:scriptBlock rendered="#{param.showDialog eq '1'}">...`

If `rendered` evaluates to `false`, the client script is never sent, so the dialog will not be automatically opened.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tim.  I could not get your sample to work.  I am sure it was something I did wrong.   I went with the below.  More complicated but it works for me and need to move on:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
   name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
   var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
   return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

if (getParameterByName('msg') != "")
    XSP.openDialog('#{id:dlgMessage}')
```