# Show Dialog Box from Extension Libray while server side processing

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have a XPage where it has code in the **beforeRenderResponse** event which exports data to Excel.

I would like to have the "Please wait..." dialog box that I created from the extension library to appear before the export starts.  I tried `getComponent("dialogbox").show()` but it appears to ignore that line before the export starts.

Do you have any suggestions of how to display the dialog box on the XPage in either SSJS or CSJS?  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Edited to add the XPages and Customer Control code.

XPages code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="false"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    xmlns:xp_1="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/Web Report Functions.jss"     clientSide="false"></xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:this.afterRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:/*...(export to excel code)...*/}]]></xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
    <xc:WaitDialogBox></xc:WaitDialogBox>
    <xp:scriptBlock id="showDialog">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[XSP.addOnLoad(function(){XSP.openDialog("#{id:WaitDialog}");});]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
</xp:view>
```

Custom control code "WaitDialogBox":

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xe:dialog id="WaitDialog" title="Please wait...">
    <xp:table>
    <xp:tr>
    <xp:td>
    Processing....
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    Please wait until you see the &quot;Do you want to open or save...&quot; bar on the bottom of your screen.
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    <xp:tr>
    <xp:td style="padding-top:10px;margin-top:10px;text-align:center;">
    <xp:image url="/ajax-loader.gif" id="processImage"></xp:image>
    </xp:td>
    </xp:tr>
    </xp:table></xe:dialog>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/21102700/2065611

Comment: Thank you, Knut, for your prompt assistance!  I added the script block with the following line, XSP.addOnLoad(function(){XSP.openDialog("#{id:WaitDialog}");});, but the dialog box did not appear.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add your XPage code to your question - including the dialog box but without the Excel export code (= all the relevant code).

Comment: I added the XPage and Custom Control code to my original post.  I hope I added it correctly since I'm new to this site.  :-)

Comment: Your code works for me except for theme "Bootstrap4". I had to delete `<xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/Web Report Functions.jss"     clientSide="false"></xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>`. Maybe there is an issue and page doesn't load because of this JavaScript file?

Comment: I removed the JavaScript library and I was not able to load the dialog box.  The file is used for the export so I didn't think it was affecting the dialog box.  I did notice that the dialog box appears if I call it from a button but not when the page opens.  Does the page needs to be refreshed automatically?

Comment: Hmm, it works for me. When I open the XPage in browser it shows the dialog box right away. I use Release 9.0.1FP9 on client and server.

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work for me.  I use Release 9.01 on client and server too although I don't know about the FixPack.  Should I use a dojo dialog instead?

Comment: Create a new database for test purposes and create the XPage and CC from above. I think it will work for you then too. Go from there to find to real issue.

Comment: Thank you, Knut.  It appears that the dialog box does appear if it is on its own.  However, adding code in the afterRenderResponse stops the dialog box from appearing.

Comment: Move your code to event "afterPageLoad".

Comment: I see multiple problems in your example. First of all, you've set rendered="false" on the view root tag. This prevents the script tag to be rendered and therefore the dialog can not be loaded. Maybe that's what make sense for the export but not for the dialog.
Second, if you use the afterRenderResponse event, this event will be executed twice. Once on first page load, once again when the dialog is shown (dialog open triggers a partial refresh). How do you realized the excel export? Do you write the data to the response writer of facesContext?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Adrian.  Yes, I am using the response writer to write the data.  My code is similar to the Export to Excel example in the NotesIn9 Cheat Sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you want to show a message while the export is running (regardless what kind of message, dialogbox or the dojo standby as proposed by Howard), you must ensure that the page is loading first without doing the export and start the export then.

On my sample page take a look at the rendered property on the view tag. I do there a check if a param `export` is on the request url. This is also done at the beginning of the `afterRenderResponse` event.

Then in the `showDialog` script block, I open the dialog and change the url of current window by adding `?export=true`. You are free to replace the dialog with anything else. With this solution it's not possible to do something (i.e. close the dialog) when the export is finished and ready for download.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom"
    rendered="#{javascript:param.get('export') != 'true'}">
    <xp:this.afterRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
    if(param.get('export') == 'true'){
        /*...(export to excel code)...*/
    }}]]></xp:this.afterRenderResponse>
    <xc:WaitDialogBox></xc:WaitDialogBox>
    <xp:scriptBlock id="showDialog">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[
XSP.addOnLoad(function(){
    XSP.openDialog("#{id:WaitDialog}");
    location.href='#{javascript:return context.getUrl().getPath()}?export=true';
});]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:scriptBlock>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Adrian - Thank you for your help!  This worked great for me.  The only thing is that I was hoping that it would stay on the same page and the export works behind the scenes.

Comment: The problem is, that you must ensure that the page is rendered first before the export starts. Afterwards it's not easy to get the file as a download with AJAX because a file download must be a full page load. This can be done with the approach above in the solution or with an iframe:

require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/query", "dojo/io/iframe"], function(ready, query, ioIframe){
 ready(function(){
  ioIframe.send({
   url: '#{javascript:return context.getUrl().getPath()}?export=true',
   form: query('form')[0].id
  });
 });
});

Comment: Thanks, Adrian.  If I was to use a iframe, am I opening the entire page in the iframe or just the dialog box?

Comment: The entire page should be rendered normally. In the iframe, you just render the excel export. The iframe do you need because the download must be done separetly.

Comment: if you think my answer is helpful and correct, I would appreciate it if you accept and mark it as solution

Comment: I think that your answer was helpful.  Would I be able to contact you as I have more questions (mostly with iFrames and rendering the XAgent)?

Comment: sure... feel free to ask here in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a Please wait message while the page loads? If so, than this Notes in Nine broadcast has a better way to do it. You don't want to use a dialog box in that case.
http://www.notesin9.com/2014/04/07/notesin9-142-adding-a-please-wait-to-xpages/

Comment: Yes, that is what I was hoping to do.  Thanks, Howard, for the link and I will take a look at it.  However, when I clicked on the StandBy link from http://xpagescheatsheet.com/, the link is broken.  Either way, I'll watch the video and try to figure it out from there.

Comment: Sorry about the broken links.  Apparently that had hard coded server names.  I'll try and fix that.

Comment: David - It's OK!  At least you are aware of it now.  :-)